# Getting image out of a C# 2D jagged array

Tags: c#

One of the routines for converting PDF to images that I have to work with returns the image as 2D array.
After calling the convert function I have this:

```
byte[][] image = convertToPdf....
```

Hovering over the image variable, the debugger shows:
image {byte[1][]} and hovering over that shows
[0]{byte[124353]}

I am confused how I would could get the image into a 1d byte array in order to process or convert it to an actual image.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to convert byte[0] to image? It may be array of images

Comment: note that `byte[][] image` is a one-dimensional array whose elements are one-dimensional arrays.  This is known as a jagged array.  A proper two-dimensional array would be declared as `byte[,] image`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following:

```
byte[] pdf = image[0];
```